# Python lists (getting triplets of identical numbers from the list)

Tags: python

Assume I have a list `[12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15, etc]`

I would like my result to be the following:
`[12,12,12,13,13,13,14,14,14,15,15,15]`

The number of identical numbers in the first list can vary, but I want to get triplets for each range of the identical numbers. I assume I could iterate through the list starting from the first number `(12)` and get the first 3 identical numbers `(12,12,12)`, and then compare the numbers and once the number 12 changes to 13, get the next 3 numbers `(13,13,13)`, and so on. But I cannot think of a good approach to do it correctly. Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
updated_list = []    
curr_number = some_list[0]
curr_count = 0
for n in some_list:
    if n == curr_number
         curr_count += 1
         if not (curr_count > 3):
             updated_list.append(n)
    else:
         curr_number = n
         curr_count = 1
         updated_list.append(n)
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew! That's what I needed:) Just missed the count and else parts in my logic.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted. [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3):

I would use `itertools.groupby()` to isolate the strings of identical numbers, then use a list comprehension to create the triplets:

```
import itertools
some_list = [12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,]
updated_list = [i for k,_ in itertools.groupby(some_list) for i in [k]*3]
assert updated_list == [12,12,12,13,13,13,14,14,14,15,15,15]
```

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for a solution w/o using the additional modules since I am going to incorporate it with multiple lists, but I didn't specify it in my question. But this is useful!

Answer (score 0):

Seems as a set approach is a bit faster than itertools. If you need it sorted, less but still faster.

```
A = [12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15]

def with_set(A):
    A = set(A)
    return list(A) * 3

import itertools
def with_iter(A):
    return [i for k,_ in itertools.groupby(A) for i in [k]*3]

import timeit

print("Result with set: ", timeit.timeit(lambda:with_set(A),number = 1000))
print("Result with iter: ", timeit.timeit(lambda:with_iter(A),number = 1000))
```

Result with set:  0.008438773198370306

Result with iter:  0.018557160246834882

Answer (score 0):

Below line of code is self explanatory:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4]
A = list(set(A))  #removes duplicates
A *= 3  #multiplies the unique list 3 times
print sorted(A) # makes a new sorted list
```

Comment: Thank you Thulasi. I was looking for a good logic to use with a for loop since I am going to use it with multiple lists and types of variables, and found it.